# Angular 2 Reactive Form - Display a reset button only if form is dirty

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a reactive form and I want to display a reset button, that will reset the form values to initial.

Now, the button should only appear if **form is dirty**.

The form definition is:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(''),
  lastName: new FormControl('')
});
```

First approach that I've tried was by using `form.dirty` property of the Reactive form, but it is not what I need.
The `form.dirty` returns `true` in the scenario when the user types something in inputs, then deletes it, and form controls have the same value as initial.

The second approach is to save the initial values: `this.initialFormValue = this.form.value;`, then implement a custom function that compares the current form value with the initial one:

```
isFormDirty(): boolean {
   return JSON.stringify(this.initialFormValue) !== JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
}
```

(the comparison is not very smart, maybe I will use some Lodash function, etc, but that's not the point of the question).

```
<div *ngIf="isFormDirty()" style="color: red;">Form is really dirty</div>
```

It works, but the function is called very very often (when Angular detects changes or something) and I think that I may have some performance problems.

I think that I might use `valueChanges` observable, and emit a new value...

Do you have any other suggestions?

**Stackblitz:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jywynt

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can listen to `valueChanges` Observable where you can control how often it should be executed, for example you can use `debounceTime` to reduce calls.

```
this.form.valueChanges
 .pipe(debounceTime(50))
 .subscribe(newValue => {
   if (this.isFormDirty()) {
     this.form.markAsDirty();
   } else {
     this.form.markAsPristine();
   }
 });
```

Now you can simply use the same property `form.dirty` from `FormGroup` object:

```
<div *ngIf="form.dirty" style="color: red;">Form is really dirty</div>
<div *ngIf="!form.dirty">Form is not dirty (values are identical to initial)</div>
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-equfd2?file=src/app/app.component.html)**